# How to include specific roles in auto-complete search?

Tags: 7, users, ajax

I am using the [auto-complete module](http://drupal.org/project/search_autocomplete) for searches. It works like a charm. I am looking for to learn how to show only specific roles on the results it pulls. There are advanced areas in the configuration and I think something could be used there, yet I am not sure what.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The best way to do this is create a View of the search results you would want. e.g. If you create a view of Users with role, "editor", then Autocomplete can be used to pull only from that view. Using the Filters ability of views, this should be a relatively simple task.

http://drupal.org/project/search_autocomplete supports this feature.

Comment: Auto-complete shows results as you type. What you suggest is great but it will require that the user actually searches for something. What I need is that under the "User" search they only see as-you-type results that include only specific roles.

Comment: I am aware that autocomplete searches as you type. That's the whole purpose of autocomplete. :)

I think this bullet point from the project page makes the most sense to what I was trying to say...

"Uses either static data, external or internal URL callback or an embeded view style to easily create your suggestions set." 

That means you can have a view filtered by roles and when the user starts typing it uses that view as the "suggestion set"

Hope that clarifies it a bit.

Comment: Aha! Sorry about that friend. I totally understood AND made it work 100%. THANKS for your help! :O) @webkenny